# LabTest passed but Application does not go till the end

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

I have uploaded my apk in Test Lab firebase for Rubo test but application shows only first screen and second nothing goes forward. I have tested on other devices in firebase as well but some devices goes to 2nd screen even though it has almost 30 screens and its lab test Passed it. it does not go through all application, I have to show my all application status to my client. What I have the main issue?
[image: Lab Test]

**Note:Solution**
I didn't find the exact solution but I think click listener on my custom layout could not recognize by the firebase Lab, so I applied auto click there, so when that activity passed my other activities were working fine and all other activities showed in the screenshots and videos as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a member of Firebase Test Lab, I can look into it if you share your "matrix id". At the top of the page, you will see Firebase "Test Lab > Your App Name > matrix-...".

Comment: matrix-2kcs5p2q1s1bg